# How do I turn a daily into an encounter?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, optimization

I'm looking for something that shifts a daily power into an encounter power.  I want to take the Demigod Epic Path so I can use Blade Cascade whenever I want.  Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please peruse [the FAQ](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/faq) for information about how to ask effective questions. It's traditional to use the tags rather than the title to indicate your game system, and to provide a little more information and context so people can provide answers more easily and accurately. The more you connect the dots for us regarding your question, the more time and energy we can put into answering it!

Comment: What level are you? What books are allowed?

Comment: Also, you are aware that blade cascade has been limited to 5 attacks, right?

Answer (score 19):

### Sure you can! But it's not going to help your goal.

There are *two* epic destinies which let you turn a daily power into an encounter power. Both are level 30 features in explicitly arcane destinies.

The Archmage's

> **Archspell (30th level):** Your comprehension of the ultimate arcane formula and of the spells that constitute it reaches a new threshold. Choose one daily spell that you know. You can now cast that spell as an encounter spell (rather than as a daily spell).

And the confusingly-named Archspell's

> **Living Spell (30th level):** You can use your Signature Spell as an encounter power rather than a daily power.

So... Yes, you can turn a daily into an encounter. But not the daily you want, and the method of doing it overrides the mechanic you were hoping to use in conjunction with this effect.

Comment: The prerequisite for both of these can be met with the "Arcane Initiate" feat, making it odd but possible, right?  Oh, they both require daily _spells_.

Answer (score 7):

**To my fairly certain knowledge, there exist no paragon paths nor feats nor powers that unilaterally convert a daily into an encounter.**

Testing the null hypothesis.

1) If this exists, there exist a multitude of dailies that could serve well in an encounter.

2) There are daily stances that simply dish out *more* damage

3) Therefore, those stances would feature on epic level [DPR King 3.0 builds](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&key=0AqLk5_LGDVGIdFpLcWVGMVBaUXM1bUozYmpmeVBqcEE&hl=en_US&gid=26).

4) There is no evidence of ranger-centric builds or builds focused on this strategy. Therefore, while it's impossible to say this exists, I can say that the best minds of theoretical optimization have not found it.

Second direction.

This is clearly broken. The [broken wiki](http://community.wizards.com/charop/wiki/Broken) does not list it. Therefore it likely does not exist.

Answer (score -4):

Additionally, if you meet the requirements there is the *Lorekeeper* Epic Destiny (*PHB2* pg.173) which has:

> **Lorekeeper’s Revelation (30th level):** Choose two of your daily utility powers. Those two powers are now encounter powers for you. If you do not have two daily utility powers, you can immediately retrain your utility powers until you have two daily utility powers that then become encounter powers.

Comment: Is **Blade Cascade** a utility power though?

Comment: No it's a Ranger 15 Daily attack, but the Original question was Daily into an encounter, so I presented an option, also thanks Purple Monkey, first time here, wasn't sure on quotation rules so I paraphrased

Comment: That's just the title, not the original question. Answers should answer the actual question because titles are always a simplification.